# Writing test code for Text to json data parsing in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, tdd

I am new in rails. I have some texts files. I parse the text files to json in a predefined format. Now i need to write test code for checking text data is converting into json data or not. what tests should I check? how should I start it? which tools are better? and How I start? 
any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use rspec-rails. 
Include it in your Gemfile run the installer with

```
rails g rspec:install
```

Then create a file called NAME_spec.rb in a subdirectory of spec/.
Insert the following basic structure to your file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "something" do
   before :all do
     # Set up your text file
   end 

   it "does something" do
     # Write your test
     # use following syntax
     # expect(Something).to eq Something
   end
end
```

Read the rspec documentation for more information on this topic.